# Aerospike Error while receiving on FD: 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable)

Tags: aerospike

We are using Aerospike in cluster mode and when we enable the log severity to Debug, we are seeing error logged under debug level  `Error while receiving on FD 43: 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable)`. This is not logged as a Error severity in Aerospike though. so i am wondering is this an error we really should worry about or is this just some error Aerospike is encountering and it is handled automatically (that we can ignore in this case). we are continuously seeing this in the logs and worrying some lagging is happening.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't necessarily worry if this is only logged at Debug level and there is no noticeable impact, but I am not certain... could be simply how epol works under aggressive workloads.

Cross posted on https://discuss.aerospike.com/t/getting-fd-resource-temporaryly-unavailable-in-cluster-mode/7030

Answer (score 1):

This is an "EAGAIN" error (see http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html):

> ```
>    EAGAIN          Resource temporarily unavailable (may be the same
>                    value as EWOULDBLOCK) (POSIX.1-2001).
> ```

Means the Aerospike attempted a non-blocking operation and the socket couldn't take at this time. The server will attempt the operation again later.

This isn't anything to be concerned of, EAGAIN and EWOULDBLOCK errors are expected.